# Create delete event that deletes older records on daily basis

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I want to delete the records that is older than 1 day. What is the best way to achieve it? I have never used event before so i am having little problem.
For eg: I want to delete records where start_time is older than 1 day. 
by doing some research i got to this point.

```
CREATE EVENT deleteRecords
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO 
DELETE FROM databaseName.tableName WHERE start_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), 
INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: I have a few links off my profile page for events. Like turning things on, etc.

Comment: the best way to that is also create two trigger on this table (ON INSERT ans OND UPDATE) that store the row a a achieve table. so the delete event can run without any other action

Comment: Got any description of your table? It's a bit hard to guess whether your `start_time` is just a time or timestamp or whatever datatype. The `DELETE` function you showed is logically correct.

Comment: @rhavendc start_time is a date and time . Eg: 2014-07-08 02:29:30

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways on how to achieve your desired result.

```
//sample 1
DELETE FROM databaseName.tableName WHERE DATE_ADD(start_time,INTERVAL 1 DAY) < NOW();

//sample 2
DELETE FROM databaseName.tableName WHERE ADDTIME(start_time,"1 00:00:01") =< NOW();
```

The code in your post is okay to use too. But don't forget to backup data first if you're unsure of what you're doing.

> Reference [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)